# convert string to char* [string has '0']

Tags: c++, string, char

How do i convert a hex string to a char, whilst keeping and zero's that are within the string? I am currently doing...

```
std::string hex = "202020202020202038373c425245414b3e3c50434120546f204152542057443e150080000000000100154007000f5043412057442046524f4d204c50430001000000002d08000000003c2f50434120546f204152542057443e3c2f425245414b3e";
int len = hex.length();
    std::string newString;
    for (int i = 0; i< len; i += 2)
    {
        std::string byte = hex.substr(i, 2);
        char chr = (char)(int)strtol(byte.c_str(), NULL, 16);
        newString.push_back(chr);
    }

    //std::cout << newString;
    char *sendBuf;
    sendBuf = new char[newString.size() + 1];
    strcpy_s(sendBuf, newString.size() + 1, newString.c_str());
    std::cout << sendBuf;
```

But this gives me an output with everything converted up to the first zero after 'e150'. The hex is meant to convert to `'        87<BREAK><PCA To ART WD>€@PCA WD FROM LPC-</PCA To ART WD></BREAK>'`
but i get         `87<BREAK><PCA To ART WD>`, any suggestions for a fix?

thanks

Comment: Stop using old-fashioned string functions that quit on a null byte, such as `strcpy_s`. That's the *only* way to get null bytes in the middle of a string.

Comment: `memcpy()` should be able to copy memory containing `0`s. Give it a try. Note that it will be your responsibility to null terminate strings copied using `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is an additional convention you are not using to convert the hex string.

For example if you just modify your code adding an if statement:

```
[...]
char chr = (char)(int)strtol(byte.c_str(), NULL, 16);
if ( chr < 10 )
   continue;
[...]
```

the output would be very close to the desired one:

```
    87<BREAK><PCA To ART WD>§§@☼PCA WD FROM LPC-</PCA To ART WD></BREAK>
```

I believe the sequence in the original `hex`

```
080000000000
```

is a control sequence, not really something you wish to convert.